# Use A's QR Decomposition to determine if A is invertible and solvable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gram-schmidt

If Q = \begin{bmatrix}1&1/√6&1/3√3\\1&-1/√6&-1/3√3\\0 & √2/√3 & -1/3√3\end{bmatrix}

and R = \begin{bmatrix}2√2&1/√2&1/√2\\0&4/√6&1/√6\\0&0&1/3√3\end{bmatrix}.

Is A invertible? (no computation required) Is the system Ax=b solvable for each b in $R^3$ (give the formula for its solutions).

Comment: This is a weird question, where did you get it ?

Comment: I got it from an old final exam from my linear algebra class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A=QR$ we have: $\det(A)=\det(QR)=\det(Q)\det(R)$

Since $Q$ is orthogonal (i.e. $Q^{-1}=Q^T$), we have: $1=\det(I)=\det(QQ^T)=\det(Q)\det(Q^T)=(\det(Q))^2$ so $\det(Q)=\pm 1\neq 0$.

Since $R$ is upper triangular, and has all nonzero elements on its diagonal, $\det(R)\neq 0$.

Thus $\det(A)\neq 0\implies A$ is invertible $\implies Ax=b$ has a unique solution for every $b\in\Bbb R^3$. I'm not sure what you mean by a formula for the solution to $Ax=b$. You could find $x$ as $x=A^{-1}b=(QR)^{-1}b=R^{-1}Q^Tb$  since $A$ is invertible, but I'm not sure if this is the "formula" you're looking for.

Comment: The question provides me with no b so I'm assuming that it's asking if this system is consistent for b = {b1, b2, b3} or at least what value(s) of b make it inconsistent.

Comment: Since $A$ is invertible, the system $Ax=b$ has a unique solution for every $b\in\Bbb R^3$. So the system $Ax=b$ is certainly consistent for any and every $b$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Consider the determinant of $A$. I assume you mean the $QR$-decomposition of $A$, i.e. $A = QR$.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Just changed the title. I also added to the question. The question my teacher gave me said determining if it is invertible requires no computation.

Comment: @Paul It does not require any computations indeed. Any orthogonal matrix has determinant of modulus $1$ and a upper triangular matrix with non-zero diagonal elements does also have non-zero determinant. Hence $A$ is invertible.